# how to make a phone as a projector to project onto a wall whatever is displayed on the phone screen

Tags: android, iphone

I like this concept as shown in the YouTube [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_WdBVrY3bI)
But not sure how it is possible for real application. Is it possible to implement as shown in the YouTube. SamSung has GalaxyBeam, but the projector is at the top of the phone. I like to use the flash light as a projector. Is it possible to develop or silly idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cute concept...

In the video, how the screen is beaming on the wall is by using airplay. If you purchase a projector with airplay feature, you can do the same.

Using the built in led of the iphone as a projector (like seen in the video) is just a concept and currently not possible. They also used airplay for filming this concept.

I don't think that such a feature will even be in iPhone6 and I'm sure it will create battery issues...

There are some 3rd party options. You may check [one of them](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PprANK2RWdw)

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is I want to have projector and camera on the same side for some application idea. Is there any projector in the market?